# Open URLs in a single UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I tried to open multiple URLs in a row in a single UIWebView but it only open the last URL (last member of the `macArray`).

```
- (IBAction)openURL:(id)sender {

    macArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", @"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", nil];

    NSString *part1URL = @"http://myurl?mac=";
    NSString *part2URL = @"&dothis";

    for (int i = 0; i < macArray.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", macArray[i]);

        NSString *mac = [macArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *beginURL = [part1URL stringByAppendingString:mac];
        NSString *URL = [beginURL stringByAppendingString:part2URL];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you in advance and have a good day / night.

Comment: Try "NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestObj returningResponse:&response error:&error];" instead of "[webView loadRequest:request];"

Comment: With NSError *error; & NSURLResponse *response; it works pretty well thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this to my program:

```
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

and delete that:

```
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: FYI: `sendSynchronousRequest` will block the thread that sends it - you probably don't want to do that on the main thread because the UI will freeze!

Comment: @deanWombourne : So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 6):

You can't open more than one URL in a web view!

Why not use more than one web view?

---

EDIT : You're doing what?

OK, a UIWebView is very much for rendering and displaying a web page. If you want to just send a web request, what's wrong with [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or a library like [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)?

Comment: It's a hidden web view. I just use it to send my order (who is contained in the URL).

Comment: Wat?? :O You're doing what?

Comment: `UIWebView` is an UI element and it's only purpose is to be shown on the screen. If you want to send data find another way.